# How to resolve sircular dependencies in EF Core 2.1 initialization seed?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, seeding, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have forum data entities:

`Topic`
  - Id
  - Title
  - Text
  - LastMessageId  *(nullable)*

`Message`
  - Id
  - Text
  - TopicId

I need to seed it using new Entity Framework Core 2.1 system of seeding in `OnModelCreating` in `ApplicationDbContext` using `_builder.Entity<>().HasData` function.

But there is a problem.

I have Topic and messages in it. But if I try to set `LastMessageId` in topic system faild with exception

> Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in
>   the data to be saved: 'Topic [Added] <- Messages Topic {
>   'TopicId' } Message [Added] <- LastMessage { 'LastMessageId' }
>   Topic [Added]

How correctly seed this?

Comment: I think it's impossible with the `HasData` design.

Comment: @Ivan Sad. I think to make simple function run after initial Seed to resolve it, in classic seed design.

Comment: @Ivan Need to add, that `LastMessageId` is nullable.

Comment: I understand. Another thing which comes to my mind is to create a migration with `LastMessageId` being `null`, then change the `HasData` to include the desired `LastMessageId` and generate a new migration. Not sure if it will work though, and can't try right now.

Comment: @Ivan I am not sure that `HasData` can update data. If it can mabe its possible to do inside one migration, but I tried. 1 Seed all exept `LastMessageId`. 2 Seed `LastMessageId`, but failed.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I wasn't sure either. The idea was based on [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data): *"Then EF Core migrations can automatically compute what insert, update or delete operations need to be applied when upgrading the database to a new version of the model."* and *"Migrations only considers model changes when determining what operation should be performed to get the seed data into the desired state"*. But if it doesn't work as you said, then switching to the "classic" approach is the only option I guess.